# Android Why Facebook SDK Logout button not showing?

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, androiddesignsupport, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have developed an app with facebook login, there is no problem in the login process. But I do not see the button when I want to logout.

**Broken App Screenshot**

[image: BROKEN APP]

**Working App Screenshot**

[image: WORKING APP]

Broken app gradle files;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ex.ex"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // Glide image library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What is the source of the problem? How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably useful if you post the Activity code & xml stuff. Probably a check that if you are logged in you don't show button.

Comment: The `AlertDialog` that opens after you click on the Facebook button comes with the Facebook SDK or is part of your app?

Comment: Did you find any solution, i am also facing the same issue. Please help

Comment: try to change your sdk version

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to solve it? I tried changing the sdk version but it didn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Follow [Facebook for Android Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

and use Latest Version  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'`

[Follow this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have used LoginButton widget of Facebook android sdk.

When you click logout of LoginButton widget following code executes :

```
    protected void performLogout(Context context) {
        final LoginManager loginManager = getLoginManager();
        if (confirmLogout) {
            // Create a confirmation dialog
            String logout = getResources().getString(
                    R.string.com_facebook_loginview_log_out_action);
            String cancel = getResources().getString(
                    R.string.com_facebook_loginview_cancel_action);
            String message;
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if (profile != null && profile.getName() != null) {
                message = String.format(
                        getResources().getString(
                                R.string.com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_as),
                        profile.getName());
            } else {
                message = getResources().getString(
                        R.string.com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook);
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(message)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton(logout, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            loginManager.logOut();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(cancel, null);
            builder.create().show();
        } else {
            loginManager.logOut();
        }
```

}

confirmLogout flag is by default set to true unless specified false in widget xml file:

```
confirmLogout = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.com_facebook_login_view_com_facebook_confirm_logout, true);
```

So please check your xml file whether confirm_logout is set to false.
But in that case, user will be logged out silently without displaying alert dialog.

Please post your jave code and xml code, if problem is still not resolved.

Comment: I checked the confirmLogout and it's set to true, but I still face the same issue as OP, do you have any idea what else I can do?